# How to Calculate Sale Percentage on C# Form

Tags: c#

I haven't used C# in many years an need basically a 1 liner.
I have created a bus ticket booking form of which I have a combobox for destinations and radio button for Class Types.
The Middle class price from JHB to PTA is R85.50, 
Economy price is 30% off the middle class
and Luxury 50% extra from the Middle Class.

So when the Total button is clicked then

```
private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((CboxDestination.Text == "JHB To PTA")&&(rdbEconomy.Checked))
        {

            lblTotal = ???;
```

Ive tried my calculations but i get different errors, 1 being that i'm trying to use a double on a string.
I had already tried declaring JHbToPTA as a double.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Railway_Booking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Double JHBToPTA = 85.50;
```

Please anyone help fill in the correct calculation, i'm really bad in percentages but the answer should = to 59.85

Comment: You just need to multiply by 0.7 to get a 30% discount ( = (100-30)/100 ). You might want to use decimal not double for currency, and probably look up the fares from somewhere rather than hard-coding a list in the form.

Comment: great I'll try that

Answer (score 3):

Seems like my issue was not really about the Math.
 I worked it out like so:`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        decimal ToPTA = 85.50m;
        decimal discount = (0.7m/ 100) *100;
```

`
so added an m to my decimals

And then my label display converted to string

```
 lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(ToPTA *  discount);
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

it's okay, I'm also weak in maths, but there's a simple formula for percentage.

if you want to get a percentage, the formula is:
**(marks you got / total marks) * 100**

if you have Got percentage, but don't know how much marks you have got(but you do know the total marks) then the formula will be:
**My Marks = (Total marks * percentage marks) / 100**

in your case, I can see that you have declared JHBToPTA as a "double" type, but since it's currency, you should have chosen the "decimal" type. it'll be more convenient.

since the economy price is 30% of the middle class,
then to get the price the formula will be,

**(30 * 85.50) / 100 = 25.65**

so,  if you give a discount of 30 percent, then you just have to subtract 25.65 from the middle-class price i.e. 85.50 - 25.65 = 59.85

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Railway_Booking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        decimal JHBToPTA = 85.50;
        decimal discount = (30 * JHBToPTA) / 100
        decimal final_price = JHBToPTA - discount  //i.e. 59.85
```

Comment: That structure way better than what I have,lol. Ok I'm going to try it. Thanks so much